# Was the Yuuzhang Vong's 'biot' Force dead?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

As many of us might know, the *Yuuzhang Vong*, were immune to a lot of the force. I was wondering if their biot (basically the Vong's biotech) were also Force dead and what evidence exists to prove this?

Comment: Never mind I figured it out

Comment: Well apparently Vong could not be detected trough Force, so it is quite plaussible that their biots were also separated from the Force, otherwise Jedi/Sith would detect them. Also, there was special power that allowed detection of Vong, but it was separate from the Force . http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vongsense

Comment: @Edlothiad What were you able to figure out?

Comment: @LoverofPhysics what "Force dead" meant